# Set value for dropdown inside user control using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have created UserControl for RadComboBox. I am trying to set its value on my .aspx page using Javascript. I am getting combo as null. How can I access the control which is inside of the user control? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
    combo.SetValue(MyArgs[2]);
</script>
```

Comment: where is this script, in page or UserControl?

Answer (score 3):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe you can use server side script inside the JS script tags.

You can pass the client ID to a hidden field using and asp Literal though. Jor example:

put an ASP Literal on your aspx page called fieldID

set the value to
`"<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"theID\" value=\""+RadComboBox1.ClientID+"\"/>"`

Then your JS combo would be equal to `$('#'+$('#theID').val());`

Comment: He's using Telerik's client-side API. What he's doing to get a reference to the combo box should work; however, I don't think he can do `combo.SetValue()`. For what I recall, there's no such method.

Comment: Putting `<%=  %>` inside of a `<script type="text/javascript">` wont work, at least in .net 2.0 and newer as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

From the Telerik Documentation

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/combo_client_model.html

```
function SetValueOfTheComboBox()
   {
       var combo = <%=RadComboBox1.ClientID %>;
       combo.SetValue("CustomText");
   }
```

I don't think you need the $find().

I haven't tested this, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RadComboBox for ASP.NET AJAX then the following code should work:

```
function FunctionName(parameter)
{
     var combo = $find("<$= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
     combo.set_value(parameter);
}
```

The SetValue() method is for the ASP.NET Classic controls, so if you are using ASP.NET AJAX you need to use the new client-side API which can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html). Also keep in mind that you should write `var` before the initialization of "combo".